# Select 2 matching columns on base of 3rd column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to match id's of column 1 from column 2.

```
_________________________________
| uid  |  profile_id |   status |
|------|-------------|-----------
|  1   |   2         |  checked |
|  2   |   1         |  checked |
|  3   |   4         | unchecked|
|  4   |   1         | unchecked|
|  4   |   3         |  checked |
|  1   |   4         |  checked |
           ...
```

This is my table. I want to show the result of same values that match from id1 to id2 and status is checked. Following is the output:

```
__________________________
| uid  |  profile_id |   status |
|------|-------------|-----------
|  1   |   2         |  checked |
|  2   |   1         |  checked |
           ...
```

Because id1 1 check the id2 2 and vice versa.

I done the following code.

```
SELECT 
  `aa`.`uid` AS `uid`, 
  `aa`.`profile_id` AS `profile_id`, 
  `aa`.`match_type` AS `match_type` 
FROM 
  (
    `matched_profiles` `aa` 
    left join `matched_profiles` `ab` on(
      (`aa`.`uid` = `ab`.`profile_id`)
    )
  ) 
where 
  (
    (`aa`.`uid` = `ab`.`profile_id`) 
    and (`ab`.`uid` = `aa`.`profile_id`)
  );
```

but above code also show me the unchecked result.

Comment: How about `uid`  ,`profile_id` those two columns have same values?

Comment: yes both have same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  Because of the structure of the data int this table, you can do this by joining the table to itself.  You will have two sets of data, replicas of one another.

You want to make sure there is a two-way match between `uid` and `profile_id`.
You also want the status for both directions to be `checked`

```
SELECT 
 a.* 
FROM matched_profiles a
inner join matched_profiles a2 on 
    a.uid = a2.profile_id 
    and a.profile_id = a2.uid  
    and a.status = 'checked' 
    and a2.status = 'checked';
```

You have a kind of explicit/inexplicit join going on. I reformatted to be completely explicit for clarity. You just need to add a filter to make sure all `status` values are `checked`.

Below is the SQL to build your test schema, which is nice to provide when asking these questions for SO users.

```
create table matched_profiles (
  uid int, 
  profile_id int, 
  status varchar(18)
);
insert into matched_profiles 
values 
  (1, 2, 'checked'), 
  (2, 1, 'checked'), 
  (3, 4, 'unchecked'), 
  (4, 1, 'unchecked'), 
  (4, 3, 'checked'), 
  (1, 4, 'checked');
```